# Converting html file to pdf using iText in JApplet

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText for a project. My program is supposed to run from inside a browser and I need it to convert an html file to a pdf file. When I run the program from NetBeans everything works fine. I sign my jar and run the Applet in a browser and then I get this error:

`Errorjava.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.windir")`

For the purpose of this post I have made a simple JApplet code which has the same problem:

```
public class RunApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.add(new JLabel("This is a labe"));
        File f = new File("C:/ReportGen/data.html");
        File pdf = new File("C:/ReportGen/data.pdf");

        try {
            pdf.createNewFile();
            Document pdfDocument = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
            pdfDocument.open();

            XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

            FontFactoryImp imp = new FontFactoryImp();
            imp.getFont("Arial");
            FontFactory.setFontImp(imp);

            worker.parseXHtml(writer, pdfDocument, new FileInputStream(f));

            pdfDocument.close();
            writer.close();
            this.add(new JLabel(f.getAbsolutePath()));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.add(new JTextField("Error"+ex));
        }                       
    }
}
```

The html file is created and is fine, but when I create the pdf file I get the exception and the pdf file is actually created, but is corrupt and I am unable to open it. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You need the line pdf.close() before the line pdfDocument.close(). Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but NetBeans says "cannot find symbol" for the line "pdf.close()"

Answer (score 0):

First, I see this error in your question:

```
Errorjava.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.windir")
```

You need signed your applet for access to your filesystem. See this [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/spec/security-spec.doc1.html) too.

Second, I have tried following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("C:/tmp/data.htm");

        File pdf = new File("C:/tmp/data.pdf");
        Document pdfDocument = null;
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
        try {

            pdfDocument = new Document();
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
            pdfDocument.open();

            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, pdfDocument,
                    new FileInputStream(f));
            pdfDocument.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

If file data.htm (original data) is an htmlx, work fine. But if data.htm not is an xml, i get this error:

```
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag meta.
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:134)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:395)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:70)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:235)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:213)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:174)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:220)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:185)
    at main.main(main.java:44)
```

Can you try with your data and with this example? The difference is that my example isn't an applet, is an java standalone.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, however I had already found those instructions myself and followed them, but my problem persists. I must add that it's been almost a week since I encountered this problem and I really tried all the most obvious solutions. I sign my jar, but it still throws me the exception.

Comment: I believe that you don't close the FileWriter. Try fw.close(). It's possible that your pdf have now size zero or not closed. Regards

Comment: Actually that FileWriter was never used, I probably used it before and forgot to delete it. Anyway I completelty removed the FileWrtiter and still I get the same error.

Comment: Following your advice I tried to close the PdfWriter just in case, but id didn't change anything unfortunatley.

Comment: I have tried to test your code. What is the version of iText and XMLWorker?

Comment: iText - 5.3.0 XMLWorker - 1.1.4

Comment: Thank you for very much your time. You see, my original project also is a standalone. When I use this code in a standalone application it works just fine. But, my problem is I realy need it to work as an applet.

Comment: If my example work fine as standalone aplication, then I believe that your problem is in signed your applet for access to your filesystem. I suspect that the applet isn't duly signed. Repeat the procedure for signed and try again. Good look!