# com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException in Java

Tags: java, jsp

```
public class GeneratePDF {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Test11.pdf"));
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
        document.close();
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is my code for convert HTML to Pdf for Static and small content Html its working fine But for dynamic and long Html content it com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException this Excpetion please help me where am doing Wrong .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644852/converting-html-file-to-pdf-using-itext-in-japplet

Comment: what is the long html code that breaks it?

Comment: most probably you have invalid html...

Comment: I am reding content from its Url its not working for dynamic when i set as static like given Example its working but for this ( http://codepaste.net/wr5dgp ) html its not working please check

Comment: The problem is that you have invalid html. Try converting it using the HTMLWorker class

Comment: OK i m trying and let u know please wait

Comment: can u please tell me for Html Woker class which jar file we need to add?

Comment: does it work ok with HTMLWorker?

Comment: yes Thanx But now am Having Again One Problem that i want save Pdf On that Button then it should Not save to given Directory it should donload and save to pdf

Comment: see my answer here on how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716458/file-is-not-downloading-from-server/17716702#17716702 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702683/is-there-a-common-way-to-download-all-types-of-files-in-jsp/10703377#10703377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have invalid html.

Try converting it using the [HTMLWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825782/how-to-save-html-to-pdf-in-java-using-itext-library) class

Comment: can u please Integarte with My code so that i can click on Button and its download save as Pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828805/how-to-download-file-save-as-pdf-in-jsp please check this

Comment: add this below your jsp code :     File f = new File("C:\\Test.pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Test.pdf\"");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    BufferedOutputStream output =  new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte by[] = new byte[32768];
    int index;
    if (inputStream != null) {
        index = inputStream.read(by, 0, 32768);
    } else {
        index = -1;
    }
    while (index != -1) {
        output.write(by, 0, index);
        index = inputStream.read(by, 0, 32768);
    }
    output.flush();